# I want to upload a pdf format file into xampp mysql database table using django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to upload a pdf file along with other details of a person using django, Xampp Mysql. For example, along with person's name, address, phone number, I want to upload a pdf file which contains some content related to the person.

I've used the below code in modules.py to store person's name, address and contact number. After contact number, I also want to upload a pdf file to the same table using django, mysql.

modules.py

```
class person_upload(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def w_upload(request):
    name=request.POST['pname']
    address=request.POST['paddress']
    phone=request.POST['pphone']        
    insert=person_upload(name=name, address=address, phone=phone)
    insert.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The generalway of saving files in webApps is upload the file to a folder (usually webroot) and save the path to this file in the database.

So create the pdf with [this](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) for example.

Then upload with [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/) and save the link to the file in a new column in your database.

Comment: Thank you and appreciated for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add new field with FileField type like this

```
upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Comment: How can I read that field (upload) in views.py and save to XAMPP database.

Comment: If you configured your Xampp database with Django you can setup your column with  db_column="myColumnName", to read you just need to manipulare the objects.. like obj = person_upload.objects.filter( name = 'xpto).first() / obj.upload.url